# Auto update UITextfield with data from separate UITextfield

Tags: swift, notifications, uitextfield, listener, observers

I have three `UITextfields` (`customerRequestTextField` , `fundsAvailableTextField` and `amountOwedMarketTextField`) on the same ViewController.

I would like to set up the `amountOwedTextField` so that it automatically updates its field by subtracting the data entered into the other two textfields (`customerRequestTextField` - `fundsAvailableTextField`).

Should I use NSNotifications? Or a selector? Or something else?

I have tried setting up a selector, but my version does not work.

This is declared globally.

```swift
var amountOwedToMarket
```

This code is located in the `viewDidLoad()`.

```swift
amountOwedMarketTextField.text = String(amountOwedToMarket)

        amountOwedMarketTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textFieldDidChange(sender:)), for: .editingChanged)

    }
```

This is declared outside of the `viewDidLoad()`

```swift
    @objc func textFieldDidChange(sender: UITextField) -> Int {

        return Int(amountCustomerRequestTextField.text!) ?? 21

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the target to textfields that you want to listen to their changes

```
// in viewDidLoad
amountCustomerRequestTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textFieldDidChange), for: .editingChanged)  
fundsAvailableTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textFieldDidChange), for: .editingChanged)
```

---

```
@objc func textFieldDidChange(_ sender: UITextField) {  
   if let first =  Int(amountCustomerRequestTextField.text!) , let second = Int(fundsAvailableTextField.text!) { 
        amountOwedMarketTextField.text = "\(first - second)" 
   }
}
```